# Animated film about a blond boy who helps a witch and is granted a single wish as a reward

Tags: story-identification, movie, magic, animation

It is about a blond kid who basically sucks at everything. He helps a witch who rewards him by granting him one "wish" for one day. He then found a bit of a cheat and said he wanted to be the best at everything. She said that it would only last one day, but made a mistake and made it permanent. Then, the next day, he was able to read at a college level and spit so hard he broke a street light. Also, whenever he flexed his muscles, it would comically go up like five feet.

I watched it around the 2000s, so it was probably made around then. It is driving me crazy that I know this much, but I don't remember what it was called.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Did the film feature traditional 2D animation or 3D/CGI...?

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like it could be *[Gummi Tarzan](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0082486/) (AKA Rubber Tarzan)*. It was a Danish drama film released in 1981  and based on the [book of the same name](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/13639215-gummi-tarzan) by Ole Lund Kirkegaard.

The book is about Ivan Olsen, a small, average kid that is bullied in school and mocked by his father for not being very good at anything. The father calls him "Gummi Tarzan" (Rubber Tarzan) because he wants his son to be like the character, but does not live up to his expectations. After he boy meets a witch one evening he gets a potion that will grant all his wishes but only for one day.

Ivan tests the potion by wishing he was a master of spitting, which impresses his classmates. Later he tries more practical wishes like speedreading and super strength. He also takes revenge on his dad by reversing their roles and making the dad try and fail to do the things he mocked the kid for being bad at.

Finally, Ivan takes revenge on the bullies by filling their pants with water and making the worst of them drive into a lake. He ends the day by winning a football game.

The next day he tries to find the witch, again, but she has left. The book ends with things returning to the usual for Ivan, although he is strengthened by knowing he has had at least one good day.

[image]

Comment: This looks like a good match. I've added an inline link to IMDB so that OP can see some info about the film release (and a copy of the movie poster that may help them to identify the kid)

Comment: Judging by a [newer answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/280464/122024), and the the fact that the OP said they were looking for an animated film from "around the 2000s," it appears that _Gummi Tarzan_ is the right story but the wrong adaptation.

Answer (score 4):

The animated movie is called ***[Ivan the Incredible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jelly_T)*** (2012).

> *Jelly T* (Danish: *Gummi T*), also released as *Ivan the Incredible*, is a 2012 Danish 3D computer-animated comedy film directed by Michael Hegner from a screenplay by Michael W. Horsten, based on the 1975 children's book *Gummi-Tarzan* by Ole Lund Kirkegaard. It is the second film in a trilogy of computer-animated films based on children's books by Kirkegaard, following *Freddy Frogface* (2011) and preceding *Otto the Rhino* (2013).
>
> [...]
>
> **Ivan Olsen is constantly bullied at school, mostly by his father who is angry at his inabilities of being both smart and strong enough to protect himself.** Lotte, a cute girl wishes to be a friend of his but Ivan unwillingly disagrees believing he can't do anything at all. That evening, **Ivan visits a witch who makes a potion which grants Ivan the ability to be the best at everything for 24 hours, which allows him to teach his bullies a valuable lesson.**

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You could improve this answer by editing it to explain how _Ivan the Incredible_ matches the description given in the question.